# What tools use and how do continuous integration and test in Android with eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, testing, continuous-integration, robolectric

I have some experience in Android, and I have been working always with Eclipse. Now I want to start to develop doing test and continuous integration, so I have been researching in Google, but I have found so much different information, and I'm a little confused.

I have seen Jenkins as a good option for CI server, Robolectric for tests, and I have read about ant, maven and gradle, but, are this the best options? How I configure this tools to work together in Eclipse? Do you recommend me something better to start?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my part, I use Android Studio, and gradle. I use TeamCity as the continuous integration server, which supports Gradle. 
I have my unit tests launched automatically by TeamCity, using Gradle, on a desktop Android device (kind of mini-computer), it's pretty usefull. 
I've started tests with a phone plugged in USB on a TeamCity agent, that works very well too.